# My docker swarm creates a <none> images on which is keeps running when trying to update

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I just began using docker-swarm with docker-compose and I have run into a problem: when I try updating a service it creates a new image which basically is the old one except it has the name <\none> and the tag <\none> and the service keeps running on that image

I have tried rebuilding everything from scratch which did not work and I can remove the <\none> image because it says it is used in a container and cannot be forced removed either

So my question is how do I use the new build image in the container instead of the <\none>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to force update your Image using

`docker service update --force service_name`